# Check multiple files in folder if exist without specific filenames VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

im doing an application that checks or compare if the files are existing in the backup folder from another folder. I can do it with declaring a specific file or an array. like this one.

`" = file1.txt"`
`" = file2.txt"`
`"etc..."`

but how about not having specific files or array?

this is my code:

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form3
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    check()
End Sub
Sub check()

    Dim src As String = "D:\test"
    Dim dest As String = "D:\test2"

    Dim srcdir As New DirectoryInfo(src)
    Dim destdir As New DirectoryInfo(dest)
    Dim srcfile As FileInfo() = srcdir.GetFiles
    Dim destfile As FileInfo() = destdir.GetFiles

    Dim fi As FileInfo

    For Each fi In srcfile
        If fi.Name = fi.Name(destfile) Then
            MsgBox("no new files")
        Else
            MsgBox("new files detected")
        End If
    Next

    For Each fi In srcfile
        File.Copy(fi.FullName, dest & fi.Name)
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't know if I get it right but are you trying to copy files if it doesn't exist in the destination file?

Comment: if it has a new file, then yes. but i'm trying to check first if the main folder has the same files with the backup folder.

Comment: try my answer. I haven't tested it though cause I'm not on my PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    Dim filesToCopy As New ArrayList()
    For Each Dir As String In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(src) ' This will check every file from src or (D:\Test)
        Dim dirInfo As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(Dir)
        If Not System.IO.File.Exists(dest & "\" & dirInfo.Name) Then 'This will check if the file from src exists in dest (D:\Test2)
            filesToCopy.Add(dirInfo.Name)
        End If
    Next

    If filesToCopy.Count > 0 Then
        If MsgBox("There are new files found. Do you want to sync it now?", MsgBoxStyle.Question + MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Confirm") = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
            For i = 0 To filesToCopy.Count - 1
                System.IO.File.Copy(src & "\" & filesToCopy(i), dest & "\" & filesToCopy(i))
            Next
        End If
    End If
```

Edited so you can get the most of what you need.

Comment: nothing happens when I try to execute. I think it needs a `FileInfo` to get the files?

Comment: try my updated code again. Sorry for the late reply, my computer just finished updating..

Comment: thanks! it's working now! :) but I think it's not the output that I want. but it's fine.

Comment: No problem :) Have a nice day.. May the programmers' force be with you.

Comment: how do I do it without using `For Each Loop`? like `IF` statements or something, because when I put a `DialogBox` with the text `new files detected, start sync now?` with yes button, it keeps appearing with the file count, yeah because of `For Each` :) I'm thinking it would appear only once then copy all the files :) any tips?:)

Comment: You want to prompt first that there are new files then when you click "Yes" only then the copying will begin?

Comment: Post a new question about it so this question can be closed already. I'll be there to answer based on your details. I mean I'll try to answer it.

Comment: not yet sir, because the site says I can only post again tommorow :( i't won't let me post now.

Comment: I owe my life to you sir! THANKS A LOT! wew! :) you're a genius! you saved my life :)

Comment: Very much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1):

try this
u r code is working fine jst change the logic of it i alredy given in below code

```
Imports System.IO
    Public Class Form3
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        check()
    End Sub
    Sub check()

    Dim src As String = "D:\test"
    Dim dest As String = "D:\test2"

    Dim srcdir As New DirectoryInfo(src)
    Dim destdir As New DirectoryInfo(dest)
    Dim srcfile As FileInfo() = srcdir.GetFiles
    Dim destfile As FileInfo() = destdir.GetFiles

    Dim fi As FileInfo

    For Each fi In srcfile
        If If Not System.IO.File.Exists(fi.Name) Then 
            MsgBox("no new files")
            Exit sub
        Else
           For Each fi In srcfile
               File.Copy(fi.FullName, dest & fi.Name)
          Next
        End If
    Next



End Sub
```

Comment: actually my has error on `destfile` under the parenthesis of `fi.Name( )`, and I already tried that `For Each` inside the `Else` of if statement, but it has under erro under `fi` and it says `For loop control variable 'fi' already in use by an enclosing for loop`.